Почему я получаю ошибку форматирования, если все верно. #Flutter
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

class WhisperService {
  final String urlToWhisper;
  final String whisperModelVersion;
  final String whisperApiKey;

  WhisperService(
      {required this.urlToWhisper,
      required this.whisperModelVersion,
      required this.whisperApiKey});

  Future<String> startPrediction(urlToAudio) async {
    String result;
    var url = Uri.https(urlToWhisper, whisperModelVersion);
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      'version': whisperModelVersion,
      'input': {
        'audio': urlToAudio,
        "model": "large-v3",
        "translate": false,
        "temperature": 0,
        "transcription": "plain text",
        "suppress_tokens": "-1",
        "logprob_threshold": -1,
        "no_speech_threshold": 0.6,
        "condition_on_previous_text": true,
        "compression_ratio_threshold": 2.4,
        "temperature_increment_on_fallback": 0.2
      }
    }, headers: {
      'Authorization': whisperApiKey
    });
    result = response.toString();
    print(response.request);
    print(response.body);
    print(response.headers);
    return result;
  }

  Future<String> getPrediction(predictionUrl) async {
    String result;
    var url = Uri.https(predictionUrl);
    var response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {'Authorization': whisperApiKey});
    result = response.toString();
    return result;
  }
}



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

почему ты называешь ошибку с типами ошибкой форматирования? Ты передаешь объект там - где ожидается строка - поэтому и ошибка

http.post(url.toString(), body: {

Все очень просто если смотреть документацию.

body sets the body of the request. It can be a String, a List or a Map<String, String>. If it's a String, it's encoded using encoding and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will default to "text/plain".

Т.е. вы передаёте Map<String, dynamic> в body, а библиотека способна обработать только String, List<int> или Map<String, String>.
Самое простое решение вашей проблемы:
import "dart:convert";

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

class WhisperService {
  final String urlToWhisper;
  final String whisperModelVersion;
  final String whisperApiKey;

  WhisperService(
      {required this.urlToWhisper,
      required this.whisperModelVersion,
      required this.whisperApiKey});

  Future<String> startPrediction(urlToAudio) async {
    String result;
    var url = Uri.https(urlToWhisper, whisperModelVersion);
    
    final map = {
      'version': whisperModelVersion,
      'input': {
        'audio': urlToAudio,
        "model": "large-v3",
        "translate": false,
        "temperature": 0,
        "transcription": "plain text",
        "suppress_tokens": "-1",
        "logprob_threshold": -1,
        "no_speech_threshold": 0.6,
        "condition_on_previous_text": true,
        "compression_ratio_threshold": 2.4,
        "temperature_increment_on_fallback": 0.2
      }
    };
    
    final json = jsonEncode(map);
    
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json, headers: {
      'Authorization': whisperApiKey
    });
    result = response.toString();
    print(response.request);
    print(response.body);
    print(response.headers);
    return result;
  }

  Future<String> getPrediction(predictionUrl) async {
    String result;
    var url = Uri.https(predictionUrl);
    var response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {'Authorization': whisperApiKey});
    result = response.toString();
    return result;
  }
}

